# Programming challenge: restricted Permutations

Tags: function-construction, permutation

I need to generate the set of all *inequivalent* permutations for a collection of objects of the form `{symbol, integer}`.

Here is an example collection from which I would like to the obtain the permutations.

```
myList = {{a, 1}, {b, 1}, {c, 2}, {d, 2}, {e, 2}, {f, 3}}
```

Two permutations  are *equivalent* if the order of the positions of second element (`integer`) are the same in the two permutations.  Here are two *equivalent* permutations (and therefore, only one of them should be included in the final output):

```
{{a, 1}, {c, 2}, {b, 1}, {d, 2}, {e, 2}, {f, 3}}

{{a, 1}, {e, 2}, {b, 1}, {c, 2}, {d, 2}, {f, 3}}
```

`myList` should result in a total of 60 *inequivalent* permutations.

---

**Challenge:** I need the most efficient code (ideally in functional form) that does not require constructing *all* permutations with `Permutations[myList]` only to eliminate the *equivalent* one.  It needs to be fast for collections as large as 10 objects.

Comment: What have tried? Please share the code of what you have tried.

Comment: @Edmund I have been trying for two days, but I couldn't come up with anything that worked reliably other than starting with `Permutations[myList]` and removing the duplicates.  I really at a loss at how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

Here is an improved version that should be considerably faster. The main improvements are:

1. Use a compiled function instead of `Ordering @* Ordering` to compute the ranks.
   Here's an example of how the compiled function works. For a list like:
   `{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 1}}`
   I permute `{1, 3, 1}` instead of `{1, 2, 1}`. Then, the compiled function changes the second `1` to `2`.
2. Create the result by direct part extraction, and use Partition/Flatten so that only a single part extraction is needed.

Here's the code:

```
perms[list_]:=Module[{indices=list[[All,2]], len=Length[list], reps},
    reps = indices /. DeleteDuplicatesBy[Thread[Sort[indices]->Range@len], First];
    Partition[
        list[[Flatten@fc[Permutations[reps]]]],
        len
    ]
]

fc = Compile[{{v,_Integer,1}},
    Module[{r=v,dup=Table[0,{Length[v]}]},
        Do[
            r[[i]] += dup[[r[[i]]]]++,
            {i,Length[v]}
        ];
        r
    ],
    RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}
];
```

And, here's a timing comparison:

```
list = {{a,1},{b,1},{c,2},{d,2},{e,2},{f,3},{g,3},{h,4},{i,5},{j,6},{k,6},{l,8}};

r1 = perms[list]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = permit[list]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {20.5043, Null}
>
> {30.4845, Null}
>
> True

*(permit is from @ciao's answer)* Note that the majority of time is spent constructing the list. The following function just creates the permutations:

```
p1[list_] := Module[{indices=list[[All,2]], len=Length[list], reps},
    reps = indices /. DeleteDuplicatesBy[Thread[Sort[indices]->Range@len], First];
    fc[Permutations[reps]];
]
```

The timing for permutation creation is:

```
p1[list]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.96846, Null}

So, 17.5 seconds is spent just converting the permutations to the desired output. This is slow because the list is a mixture of symbols and integers. In other words, the output cannot be packed. If the input consisted strictly of integers, than the output could be packed, and the function would be much faster. For example, suppose the input is:

```
list ={{1,1},{2,1},{3,2},{4,2},{5,2},{6,3},{7,3},{8,4},{9,5},{10,6},{11,6},{12,8}};
```

Then `perms` is much faster:

```
perms[list]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {8.00287, Null}

**Old answer**

How about:

```
perms[list_]:=With[{p = Permutations[list[[All,2]]]},
    Thread[{
        list[[Ordering @ Ordering @ #, 1]],
        #
    }]& /@ p
]
```

For your test case:

```
res = perms[myList];
Column[Row[#, ","]& /@ res] //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  \{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{f,3\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{f,3\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{c,2\},\{f,3\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{f,3\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{b,1\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{f,3\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{b,1\},\{d,2\},\{f,3\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{b,1\},\{f,3\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\},\{f,3\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{b,1\},\{f,3\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\},\{f,3\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{f,3\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{f,3\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{f,3\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{f,3\},\{b,1\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{f,3\},\{d,2\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{f,3\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{f,3\},\{b,1\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{f,3\},\{c,2\},\{b,1\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{f,3\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{a,1\},\{f,3\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{f,3\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{d,2\},\{f,3\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{f,3\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{d,2\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\},\{f,3\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{d,2\},\{b,1\},\{f,3\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\},\{f,3\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{f,3\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{d,2\},\{f,3\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{d,2\},\{f,3\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{f,3\},\{b,1\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{f,3\},\{d,2\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{f,3\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\},\{f,3\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{f,3\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{a,1\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\},\{f,3\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{a,1\},\{e,2\},\{f,3\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{a,1\},\{f,3\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{a,1\},\{f,3\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{f,3\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{a,1\},\{f,3\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{f,3\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{f,3\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{f,3\},\{a,1\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{f,3\},\{e,2\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{f,3\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{f,3\},\{a,1\},\{d,2\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{f,3\},\{a,1\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{f,3\},\{d,2\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{f,3\},\{d,2\},\{a,1\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{c,2\},\{f,3\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{f,3\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{f,3\},\{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{b,1\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{f,3\},\{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{f,3\},\{a,1\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{f,3\},\{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{f,3\},\{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{d,2\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{f,3\},\{c,2\},\{a,1\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{f,3\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\},\{e,2\} \\
>  \{f,3\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{a,1\},\{e,2\},\{b,1\} \\
>  \{f,3\},\{c,2\},\{d,2\},\{e,2\},\{a,1\},\{b,1\} \\
> \end{array}$

Comment: Your second version of the answer is very enlightening; it tells me that I should work with packed arrays as far as possible until its time to generate the final result.  My code will require some rework but I think this is good to know.

Answer (score 8):

Quick-n-dirty attempt at an interesting problem:

```
permit[list_] := 
  Module[{sp, tg, idx}, 
   sp = Partition[
      Flatten[##][[Flatten[
         Ordering[Ordering[#]] & /@ 
          Permutations[Flatten[MapIndexed[(idx = #2[[1]]; idx & /@ #1) &, ##]]]]]], Length[Flatten[##]]] &;
   tg = GatherBy[Transpose[{Range@Length@list, list}], #[[2, -1]] &][[All, All, 1]];
   Replace[sp@tg, AssociationThread[Range@Length@list, list], {2}]];
```

Using this test list with a dozen objects, pretty quick.

```
listx = {{a, 1}, {b, 1}, {c, 2}, {d, 2}, {e, 2}, {f, 3}, {g, 3}, {h, 4}, {i, 5}, {j, 6}, {k, 6}, {l, 8}};
```

Answer (score 3):

Let

```
myList = {{a, 1}, {b, 1}, {c, 2}, {d, 2}, {e, 2}, {f, 3}};
```

Naïve solution:

```
naive[list_] := DeleteDuplicatesBy[Permutations[list], Map[Last]]
```

My non-brute-force approach:

```
aft[list_] := Module[{sym = First /@ list, int = Last /@ list},
               (
                Permute[sym, #] & /@
                 (
                  Flatten[Last /@ Sort[Normal@PositionIndex[#]]] & /@ Permutations[int]
                 )
                ) /. (list /. {A_, B_} :> Rule[A, {A, B}])
              ]
```

For comparison, let me denote the solutions by ciao and Carl Woll as

```
ciao[list_] := ...
woll[list_] := ...
```

With this,

```
naive[myList] == aft[myList] == ciao[myList] == woll[myList]
(* True *)
```

and

```
naive[myList] // Length // RepeatedTiming
aft[myList] // Length // RepeatedTiming
ciao[myList] // Length // RepeatedTiming
woll[myList] // Length // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.00253, 60}
   {0.00081, 60}
   {0.00026, 60}
   {0.00029, 60} *)
```

so that the best approach is the one by ciao. This is much more obvious if we introduce a larger list,

```
myList2 = {{a, 1}, {b, 1}, {c, 2}, {d, 2}, {e, 2}, {f, 3}, {g, 3}, {h,
 4}, {i, 5}, {j, 6}, {k, 6}, {l, 8}};
```

so that

```
aft[myList2] == ciao[myList2] == woll[myList2]
(* True *)
```

and

```
aft[myList2] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
ciao[myList2] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
woll[myList2] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
(* {274.962, 9979200}
   {26.2701, 9979200}
   {225.609, 9979200} *)
```

**In conclusion:** the approach by ciao is the most efficient one. Mine and Carl's are similar efficiency-wise, but his is much more readable. For small input you may use the solution by Carl Woll if you want a readable solution; for larger input, you should go with ciao's.

--

Some comments: first, this looks like graph theory. Although I don't know what you are trying to do exactly,  recall that MMA has a lot of built-ins, so perhaps there is a function that does a better job when you consider the big picture. Second, if someone else comes up with a different method, leave a comment below and I'll add your approach to the comparative here. Cheers!

Comment: The comparative analysis is useful; thanks!  Would you kindly also add Woll;s second version of his code to your study?